# Is it possible to show all the submits from a Perforce depot without having to select a job?

Tags: jenkins, perforce

We are currently attempting to setup an instance of Jenkins as our build system for our code base.  We have multiple jobs setup (all using the same depot) to build different sections of the code.

We would now like to show the submits from all users pertaining to this depot on the main Jenkins screen rather than being able to view the change lists involved with a certain build (e.g. by selecting a certain job and then the link leading to the build information, etc...).  I've looked into possible plugins and the closest one I was able to find was the "All Changes Plugin".  This is exactly what we would like, but this is only visible when viewing the details of a build (e.g. which CLs were used to create the build), but would it be possible to show this type of information on the main Jenkins page instead?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an extension for the Dashboard View plugin to provide a portlet containing an aggregated list of changes from perforce, though if you aren't experienced with writing plugins then you might be better off using a separate repository browser such as Fisheye or P4Web to display your changes.